# ¿Qué es una expresión regular y para qué se usa?

Tags: validación

¿Alguien me puede explicar qué es esto? Solo de verlo me he mareado.
Estoy empezando en programación y me veo esto, sé que es para validar algo y hacer un .test pero no tengo ni idea si eso se pilla de algún sitio o tengo que aprender a ponerlo, estoy perdidísimo.[image: Const er]

Comment: Se llama *expresión regular* (regular expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues es una **expresión regular**, de ahí el nombre de la constante: er.

Se usan tanto para validar como para extraer partes específicas de una cadena de caracteres. El principio es el mismo que seguramente ya usas por ejemplo para indicar que `*.*` vale para identificar cualquier fichero, mientras que `*.jpeg` sirve para indicar solamente ficheros jpeg.

Aquí puedes ver los principales comodines que puedes encontrar en una expresión regular [en inglés]. He hecho la captura del sitio https://regex101.com/ que te permite probar tus expresiones regulares

[image: Ejemplos de expresiones regulares]

Un ejemplo clásico de expresión regular es aquella que te permite validar una dirección IPv4:

```
^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$
```

Esa expresión regular se corresponde con esta definición:

> Una dirección IPv4 consiste en cuatro octetos (secuencia de números
> binarios de 8 bits) expresados en formato decimal y separados por
> puntos.

He encontrado la expresión regular en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760050/2553194). Tanto ahí como aquí puedes preguntar por una expresión que necesites (Siempre que muestres claramente lo que quieres identificar con la expresión y tus intentos para conseguirla)

Otros ejemplos clásicos donde se usan es para verificar que una dirección de email es [válida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/2553194) o para garantizar que una contraseña sea robusta [que cumpla unos parámetros determinados de longitud mínima, que incluya caracteres especiales, ...]